# Last row in UITableView is obscured by UITabBar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that has a list of UINavigationControllers assigned to the 'viewControllers' property.

Each UINavigationController has a custom UIViewController as its 'rootController' and this custom UIViewController loads its 'view' from a .xib file. This 'view' contains a UITableView (and some other controls that are displayed when the data for the UITableView is first downloaded).

It works fine to begin with - I can see the table view for the first view controller when the first tab is selected, changing tabs displays the other table views - all is good.

My problem is, when I select a row on one of these table views a new custom view controller is instantiated, told to hide the bottom bar when pushed and then is pushed on to the navigation controller. Again - this works as expected. I see the new sub-view and the tab bar is hidden.

The problem is when I return to the previous view, the final row in my UITableView is now obscured by the tab bar (which has correctly reappeared). It seems the process of hiding the bottom bar and then showing it again when returning to the previous view has confused things.

Has anyone encountered this? Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your UITableView has not the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight (in IB, see the picture below).

[alt text http://www.quicksnapper.com/files/5161/20375276064A0C11D2C33A4_m.png](http://www.quicksnapper.com/files/5161/20375276064A0C11D2C33A4_m.png)

Comment: Picture link down. What are the steps to find it in IB? Thanks